# Is there a shortcut or macro to move the Notepad++ cursor to the next search result?

Tags: notepad++, search, cursor

I am looking to automate the cursor movement, and I do not want to manually move the mouse to click on the search result line in the text window.

How do I move to the next search result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a shortcut or macro to move the NotePad++ cursor to the next search result?

If you are in the "Find" dialog, just keep pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

If you are in the text pane containing the search results or the text pane containing the text being searched for then press <kbd>f3</kbd>.

Source [101 Shortcuts for Notepad++ 6 (Windows)](https://shortcutworld.com/Notepad-plus-plus/win/Notepad%2B%2B_6_Shortcuts)